# How to implement Mouse hover listener in vaadin chart

Tags: vaadin-charts

How can I add cursor `hover` listener in `vaadin` chart?

I want to change the icon of the cursor to a hand or similar icon to indicate that the bar in the chart is clickable?

```
public static final Cursor POINTER
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your chart ID in java.

```
myChart.setId("forzaJuve");
```

Then in your theme, you can write like this:

```
    @import "../valo/valo.scss";

    @mixin mytheme {
        @include valo;

        #forzaJuve:hover { 
    *Do whatever you want to do here*
}
```

Make sure you recompile and do clean & build to save everything.
Hope i helped :)

Comment: i given to set the id to series in the bar chart and i tried but it doesn't work ,